ASP.NET Core MVC: RedirectToRoute with default action doesn't include action in URL
This is an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC app running on IIS, ported from classic .NET. RedirectToRoute 302 URL doesn't include the action if the action is default.
Program.cs:
app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Index" });

In Controller1Controller, I have :
if (someCondition) 
{ 
    RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller2"); 
}

The Index action in Controller2 is called. But the 302 redirect is: http://PathToMyApp/Controller2, not http://PathToMyApp/Controller2/Index or even http://PathToMyApp/Controller2/.
This is an issue with routing, because http://PathToMyApp/Controller2, any AJAX call send from client will go to http://PathToMyApp/action and not http://PathToMyApp/Controller2/action.
If I go:
if (someCondition) 
{ 
    RedirectToAction("SomeOtherAction", "Controller2"); 
}

then the action is included in the route.
This is different than the behavior in classic .NET. Is this a bug in .NET Core, or is something wrong with my expectation here?

Inside asp.net core, it will check the route, if the route contains the default route rule defaults: new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Index" }, it will not add the full route , since it contains the default route.
If you want to always show all the route, try modify the MapControllerRoute method to remove the default role and then it will show all the path inside the url.
Like below:
app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
                 );

